# Checking for nil strings in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for a good shortcut for Nil checking in my Rails views. I've seen other questions on SO about this, but none seem to simplify this as much as I'd like. What I'd like is a short syntax to return an empty string `""` if a particular value is nil, otherwise return the value.

There is a suggestion [here](http://hobocentral.net/blog/2007/08/25/quiz/) which I am inclined to try out. It basically allows a statement like this:

```
user.photo._?.url
```

-- or --

```
user.photo.url._?
```

Is this a good idea or is it fraught with peril?

My other option would be to handle nils on my models, but that seems too global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic Ruby way to accomplish this is the `||` operator, which will return the value of the right-hand expression if the left-hand expression is `nil` (or `false`):

```
puts(user.photo.url || '')
```

Any moderately experienced Ruby programmer will understand exactly what that does. If you write a custom `_?` method, I now have to go look up the purpose of that method and remember what it does and hope that it always does the right thing. I generally find that sticking to idiomatic code is far more beneficial than saving a few keystrokes here and there.

Comment: Use this one with try(:url) If sometimes the user can have no photo

Comment: Great point. Plus no need to do this if there are idiomatic ways to accomplish what i'm after right in the language!

Answer (score 5):

You should check `try` method which runs a provided method on the object and returns the value if the object in question is not nil. Otherwise it'll just return nil.

Example

```
# We have a user model with name field
u = User.first

# case 1 : u is not nil
u.try(:name)
=> Foo Bar

# case 2 : u is nil
u.try(:name)
=> nil

# in your case
user.photo.try(:url)
```

For details have a look at [this blog post](http://everydayrails.com/2011/04/28/rails-try-method.html).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
user && user.photo && user.photo.url.present?
```

This will not blow up if user is nil or user.photo is nil

Comment: `#blank?` works as a combination of `#nil?` and `#empty?`. The inversion of `#blank?` is `#present?`. These will clean up your logic

Comment: oops, accidentally rolled back Dan's edit. Re-rolled back to Dan's version. My bad.

Comment: You still need to check that the url is not nil or blank. Added that to Dan's edit.

Answer (score 0):

What about just using nil?

```
someObject.nil? # true if someOBj is nil
```

Or am I misunderstanding what you want?

Comment: Well, this actually returns true or false, right? What I want is if .nil? then return "", else return value. Does that make sense? Should have probably asked the question like that in the first place, will update.

Comment: You may want to use .try(). See http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try. Also be careful about string evaluation and nil. "".nil? is false, but "".empty? is true.  Also, " ".nil? is false and " ".empty? is false. Rails gives you the blank? helper and both "".blank? and " ".blank? are true.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your options are problematic, because if photo is nil, both of your statements should return 'Undefined method'.

You shouldn't even need to check for '.nil?'. Since you implied your checking is in the view, and not in the controller, I imagine you are checking an @instance variable, which will always be nil if undefined. So just do:

```
if @someObject
  ...
else
  ...
```

If you are putting the conditional in your controller, then again, just use an @instance variable and you'll always have at least nil, if undefined.